# Does this output have a logic error?

Tags: java

`1.7 (Approximate p) p` can be computed using the following formula:

Write a program that displays the result of `4 * (1 - 1/3 + 1/5 - 1/7 + 1/9 - 1/11)`

and `4 * (1 - 1/3 + 1/5 - 1/7 + 1/9 - 1/11 + 1/13)`

Use `1.0` instead of `1` in your `3 5 7 9 11 13`
program.

My Code:

```
/**
* This program will print two different results in
* trying to reach a approximation of pi.
*
* Author: X   Date: 11/11/2013
*/
public class one_seven
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        System.out.print("This will print 1st approximation: ");
        System.out.println(4*(1.0-(1.0/3)+(1.0/5)-(1.0/7)-(1.0/11)));
        System.out.print("This will print 2nd approximation: ");
        System.out.println(4*(1.0-(1.0/3)+(1.0/5)-(1.0/7)-(1.0/11)+(1.0/13)));
    }
}
```

My output for the code is:

```
This will print 1st approximation: 2.531601731601732
This will print 2nd approximation: 2.83929403929404
```

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not useful and is nothing more than a copy/paste mistake. The OP was given an equation to approximate pi and simply failed to re-write the equation correctly. 

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing the `1.0/9` term.

```
 System.out.print("This will print 1st approximation: ");
 System.out.println(4*(1.0-(1.0/3)+(1.0/5)-(1.0/7)+(1.0/9)-(1.0/11)));
 System.out.print("This will print 2nd approximation: ");
 System.out.println(4*(1.0-(1.0/3)+(1.0/5)-(1.0/7)+(1.0/9)-(1.0/11)+(1.0/13)));
```

Comment: If I added that will that result to the correct answer then? Just want to make sure if that is the proper coding style for the formula where I won't get a logic error?

Comment: @user2522055: Try it out and see if it works. I don't think you have a logic error, it seems right except for that.

Comment: @user2522055 - Why don't you try it and find out? What do you mean by "_logic error_"? You were given the exact formula and don't need to do anything but copy it into your program...

Comment: Just wanted to make sure that the way I wrote the print statement to calculate the formula would not create a logic error where it produced the wrong answer (implying that the 1.0/9 was in it). I am just getting to learn Java and I want to make sure I understand the correct way of implementing this so I won't get confused by the concept of precedence and to make sure that I correctly added the parentheses where there is no way of me getting a logic error. An error where my answer was not the one expected. @jahroy

Answer (score 0):

In both approximations you left out + (1.0/9.0)

Comment: If I didn't leave that out is my coding style correct for me to get the correct answer without a logic error?